# An Issue with event mapping after rotating an image DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have applied transform on an image and also on a view which is holding that image.
The parent view that hold an image has two more small images at its edges, where I handled mouse events to rotate an image.

Now once the image is rotated , I was unable to get mouse events on edges of the parent view.
The events are taking at old positions itself.

Can anybody give me a hint what exactly going wrong ?

Comment: That is simple , I use setFrameCenterRotation on NSImageView , and I will be calculating an angle based on how the image will be rotated, I have drawn a knob with line which is used as a rotation control , as we drag the line ( drawn using Bezier path ) will calculate the angle using the formula, translated point will be difference in x,y positions of start point and end point of the rotation control knob. once it is rotated mouse events takes in original position only. 
    rotationAngle = (atan(translatedEndPoint.y / translatedEndPoint.x) * 180)/M_PI;